# Example of onBlur() in html

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone provide me an example of onBlur() event in html. I tried referring to the earlier post for this topic, however im not able to execute it. Please guide me to an example of onBlur() in html.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Events are not HTML, they're _javascript_. [This page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) should tell you what these events are and how to use them.

Comment: "however im not able to execute it" - How did you try to execute it..? Btw did you check any documentation/ tutorials or at least tried a simple [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=using+javascript+onblur+event&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=hjK-U6OOA8_V8gfR_IGQCw&gws_rd=ssl)…?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any effort or attempt made to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="name" onblur="alert('onblur attribute')">
```

The onblur attribute fires the moment that the element loses focus.

Onblur is most often used with form validation code (e.g. when the user leaves a form field).

The onblur attribute is the opposite of the onfocus attribute.

Comment: Hi Rafi Can you show a sample html code with onblur used. I tried to get info from 3schools but it was not proper.

Comment: Just Google it. i found many examples from google.

Answer (score 0):

The `onBlur()` event doesn't really need much explaining. It's the opposite of focus, so when an element loses its focus, `onBlur()` is fired. Try to give the input focus and then click outside/tab out of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/g94jZ/